# Grails 2.1 createCriteria issue with params

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

edit-

I am trying to return a list of portfolios, along with the last 5 publications attached to each portfolio from my 2 domain classes. I am getting the last total 5 publications back and each list displays all 5. The query is not returning that particular instances own publications.  Kellys great ideas put back into another track.

I have created the method in the portfolio controller which is the hasMany side to the publications which belongsTo the portfolio domain class.

I just cant seem to get the portfolios to list their own publications. If I change the eq portfolios, it all works fine, except each portfolio list shows the same publications.

How do I load each portfolio and list the last 5 publications. This is rendered from the portfolio/list page as a partial.Is this the issue maybe. Should I just render it from a new view which is not associated with the portfolio list action??

Newbie to grails and have read and read the doc's, just cant seem to get the params query to return correctly. Help

```
def _webList (){
    //def per = Portfolio.properties
    def portfolios = Portfolio.list(params.id)
    def results = Publication.withCriteria {

        eq('published', 'Yes')
        order('lastUpdated', 'desc')
        maxResults(5)
    }

    def reportscount = Publication.count()

    [ portfolios: portfolios, results: results, reportscount: reportscount]
}
```

I can show the the sql log if needed.

---

**EDIT**

The following code is the entire partial from file _webList.gsp.  The top div -alert loads on the page, but the content within the div property-list portfolio fails to load. Using Kelly's hibernate criteria produces the query in the sql log but not results or styles or anything are return to the view??. weird.!

```
<div class="alert alert-info" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">Permissions apply to    <strong>editing</strong> publications.<br>
<div style="display: inline;"><p>Click portfolio name to read or edit publications. Total number of sites: <strong>${rsNumb}</strong> | Total number of publications:  <strong>${reportscount}</strong> </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="property-list portfolio">
<g:each in="${portfolios}" var="portfolioInstance">
<div class="site-listing">
    <div><span class="label">Site Name:</span><g:link action="show" id="${portfolioInstance?.id }">${portfolioInstance?.portfolioName?.encodeAsHTML()}</g:link></div>
    <div><span class="label">Site Description:  </span>${portfolioInstance?.portdescrip?.encodeAsHTML() }</div>   <br>
    <div><span class="label">Site Administrator: </span>${portfolioInstance?.profile?.portfolioAdmin?.encodeAsHTML() }</div>   <br>
    <div><span class="label"> Total publications:</span><span class="badge badge-success"> ${portfolioInstance?.publications?.size()}</span> </div>
 <!-- whatever else you need here -->
 <!-- now iterate through the pubs -->
    <g:if test="${portfolioInstance?.publications}">
        <g:set var="publicationInstance" />
            <ul class="site-publication">
                 <li class="fieldcontain">
                     <span id="publications-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="portfolio.publications.label" default="Last 5 published publications:" /></span>
                         <g:each in="${portfolioInstance.publications}" var="publicationInstance">
                             ${publicationInstance?.id}
                                <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="publications-label"><g:link controller="publication" action="show" id="${publicationInstance.id}">${publicationInstance?.encodeAsHTML()}</g:link></span>
<!-- and again whatever else you need here -->
                         </g:each>
        </g:if>
</g:each>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT** - sql log below

```
Hibernate: select this_.id as id5_1_, this_.version as version5_1_, this_.date_created as date3_5_1_, this_.last_updated as last4_5_1_, 
this_.portdescrip as portdesc5_5_1_, this_.portfolio_name as portfolio6_5_1_,   this_.portpublished as portpubl7_5_1_, this_.profile_id as profile8_5_1_, 
this_.status as status5_1_, 
publicatio1_.portfolio_id as portfolio5_5_3_, 
publicatio1_.id as id3_, publicatio1_.id as id2_0_, 
publicatio1_.version as version2_0_, 
publicatio1_.date_created as date3_2_0_, 
publicatio1_.last_updated as last4_2_0_, 
publicatio1_.portfolio_id as portfolio5_2_0_, 
publicatio1_.publication_content as publicat6_2_0_, 
publicatio1_.publication_name as publicat7_2_0_, 
publicatio1_.published as published2_0_, 
publicatio1_.publisheddate as publishe9_2_0_, 
publicatio1_.publishedemail as publish10_2_0_, 
publicatio1_.pubproduct_id as pubproduct11_2_0_ 
from portfolio this_ left outer join publication publicatio1_ 
on this_.id=publicatio1_.portfolio_id where (this_.status=?) 
and (publicatio1_.published=?) order by publicatio1_.last_updated desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the `java.lang.ClassCastException` because `portfolios` is a list and `portfolio` in the `Publication` class (probably) isn't, it's probably an id (long); can't cast a list in any meaningful way to compare to a long in `eq ('portfolio', portfolios)`

You should not need two separate queries since the domain classes are related.

--EDIT--
Editing to not use separate action and just use list action. I've not been able to get the `include` to work either, but below is pretty much what I've in dozens of cases.  If there is some reason you can't do this then maybe a new question on just using the `include` mechanism might generate some attention.

I'm not sure what your current list action looks like.  This is how I would code a list method to get ALL Portfolios  and their last 5 Publications.  No need for any parameters because I'm returning ALL portfolios.

```
//PortfolioController
def list (){ 
    def portfolios = Portfolio.createCriteria().list {
        //if you needed to filter the list by for example portfolio status or something you could add that here
        or {
            eq('status','ACTIVE')
            eq('status','PENDING')
        }
        publications(org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN) {
            eq("published", "Yes")
            order("lastUpdated", "desc")
            firstResult(5)
        }
    }

    [portfolios: portfolios, portfolioCount:portfolios.size()]
}
```

Now the Publications come pre-attached to their Portfolio.

The LEFT_JOIN part of the above insures you get back a list of portfolios with ONLY those Publications attached that meet the criteria; if you leave that out it defaults to an inner join and when you iterate you will get ALL of the Publications for that Portfolio (even if they don't meet the criteria).

Then in your gsp iterate through the portfolios - it can either be directly in the  `list.gsp` or in a template rendered in `list.gsp`. If you put it in a template called `_webList.gsp` you would render it in the `list.gsp` as

```
<g:render template="weblist" model="['portfolios': portfolios]" />
```

This is either in `list.gsp` or `_webList.gsp` - I would start with it directly in `list.gsp` to make sure it's all working.

```
<g:each in="${portfolios}" var="portfolioInstance" status="i">
    ${portfolioInstance?.portfolioName?.encodeAsHTML()
    <!-- whatever else you need here -->
    <!-- now iterate through the pubs -->
    <g:each in="${portfolioInstance.publications"} var="publicationInstance" status="j">
        ${publicationInstance.id}
        <!-- and again whatever else you need here -->
    </g:each>
</g:each>
```

--EDIT--
`firstResult(5)` seems to do the trick.
--EDIT--

You'll notice I have the `maxResults(5)` commented in there - I'm having trouble getting that to work correctly.  It seems to control the number of portfolios that are returned even though it is in the association block.  Maybe someone else will see this and add that piece of the puzzle - or tinker with it yourself.  I'll keep trying and update if I figure it out.

Comment: thanks mate, this makes sense to me. Coming from a ruby world, I was having issues with the criteria. You have explained alot just in this short space. I really appreciate it. I will try it later and let you know the outcome.

Comment: OK, I think I figured it out.  Updated the answer to use `firstResult(5)` and in my test that seems to do everything you want!  Let me know if this works...

Comment: Kelly, Ok so the sql log shows the query working, but the gsp iterate is not loading anything. I should mention that the view code is in a partial template within the portfolio directory "_weblist.gsp". I have the following in the portfolio/list.gsp this code  <g:include controller="portfolio" action="_webList" />   weird that it is not displaying

Comment: You might have to pass the variable from the main page to the template something lik:  `<g:render template="/portfolio/weblist" model="['portfolios': portfolios]" />`

Comment: hmm still nothing. I have to duck out but will be back on it later

Comment: g:render does not display any part of the /portfolio/_webList.gsp when rendered in /portfolio/list.gsp.  What does start to display is the following, <g:include action="_webList" model="['portfolios': portfolios]" />

Comment: I've never used `includes` like this, so I'm kind of guessing at this point.  The framework may be having trouble with the names - anything that starts with `_` is treated as a template, but `include` wants to include a view (e.g. not starting with `_`). Sorry to keep asking you to try stuff but how about this: rename the view as `webList.gsp` and the action as `webList()` then use include like this `<g:include action='webList' controller='portfolio' />`

Comment: ok still nothing. I have tried every permeation of naming, g:includes, g:render with model or without. still cant seem to get the g:each to load on the page, however the queries are being run. I have updated the main questions with the partial view code

Comment: OK, this is truly pretty weird. I've tried this as well and the include just doesn't seem to want to do what it should.  I'm going to edit my answer to encapsulates what we've worked through but does things the way I've always done them for similar pages.

Comment: yes truly weird behaviour. I have placed the view code directly into the list view, but get no results back  however sql log shows it running. Im going to try your above edited code directly in pages and using the list action you describe. lets try and see what happens. I will work back from there. thanks for  you time on this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20429/discussion-between-iann-and-kelly)